# MySql Select Query is not acting properly

Tags: java, mysql, sql, search, select

I want to search in a Date column.

**I use this query:**

```
SELECT * FROM requestserverdb.closedrequests 
WHERE
ClosingTimeStamp >= '2014-09-04' 
AND 
ClosingTimeStamp <= '2014-09-19';
```

**I only get results from 04-09-2014 to 18-09-2014** , it **does not include the last day** !

also if I use:

```
SELECT * FROM requestserverdb.closedrequests 
WHERE
ClosingTimeStamp >= '2014-09-04' 
AND 
ClosingTimeStamp <= '2014-09-04';
```

**I will not get any results at all !**

how come ?

what am I doing wrong ?

its just ignores the '=' sign...

please help :)

**Dave.**

Comment: What datatype the the `ClosingTimeStamp` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option for solving this is to add "23:59:59" to the end of the date. This would make things easier in automatically generated queries than bothering with advancing the date one day. Plus if you set it ahead a day and you actually have a closed request with the timestamp of '2014-09-20 00:00:00' that WILL be included in the results. Which I would assume you do not want. You could do this instead.

```
SELECT * FROM requestserverdb.closedrequests 
WHERE
ClosingTimeStamp >= '2014-09-04' 
AND 
ClosingTimeStamp <= '2014-09-19 23:59:59';
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `'2014-09-19'` means 19 September 2014 at midnight (00:00:00), so the query won't return any records with `ClosingTimeStamp` equals `2014-09-19 09:25:00` for example. You should add one day to the upper bound of the second where condition and make it `<` instead of `<=` to avoid the query from returning any record with `ClosingTimeStamp` equals `2014-09-20 00:00:00`

```
SELECT * FROM requestserverdb.closedrequests 
WHERE
ClosingTimeStamp >= '2014-09-04' 
AND 
ClosingTimeStamp < '2014-09-20';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your string to DateTime with time part:

```
SELECT * FROM requestserverdb.closedrequests 
WHERE
ClosingTimeStamp between STR_TO_DATE('2014-09-04 0:0:0' , '%Y/%c/%d %H:%i:%s')) AND 
STR_TO_DATE('2014-09-19 23:59:59' , '%Y/%c/%d %H:%i:%s'))
```